# Running a Node.js TypeScript App on Cyclic.sh from a repo subdirectory

Tags: node.js, typescript, cyclic

I am trying to run a Node.js TypeScript app on Cyclic.sh from a subdirectory in the repo and I am having trouble. There is nothing in their tutorials about both TypeScript and a subdirectory, so I am looking for some guidance here. My specs:

**The repo**

- https://github.com/blubberbo/LolPickem

**Cyclic (advanced) Build Options**:

- Runtime: `Node 18.12.1`
- Root Path: `/lol-pickem-api`
- Output Path: `lol-pickem-api/dist`

**/lol-pickem-api/package.json**

```
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "start:watch": "rm -rf \"./dist/*\" && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node -r source-map-support/register .\"",
    "debug": "rm -rf \"./dist/*\" && tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node --inspect -r source-map-support/register .\""
  },
```

**/lol-pickem-api/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "./package.json"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**The errors:**

```
2023-07-18 16:40:31.061: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/dist/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
2023-07-18 16:40:31.076: 

2023-07-18 16:40:31.076: ERROR: Failed to run "npm run start". Start script defined in package.json:

            "scripts": {
                "start":  "node dist/server.js"
                 ...
            
Exited with code: 1
2023-07-18 16:40:31.088: [CYCLIC] ERROR: No response from server on port 3000
2023-07-18 16:40:31.593: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/dist/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}


ERROR: Failed to run "npm run start". Start script defined in package.json:

            "scripts": {
                "start":  "node dist/server.js"
                 ...
            
Exited with code: 1
2023-07-18 16:40:31.733: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/dist/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
2023-07-18 16:40:31.751: 

2023-07-18 16:40:31.751: ERROR: Failed to run "npm run start". Start script defined in package.json:

            "scripts": {
                "start":  "node dist/server.js"
                 ...
            
2023-07-18 16:40:31.751: Exited with code: 1
2023-07-18 16:40:31.759: [CYCLIC] ERROR: No response from server on port 3000
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"start": "node src/server.js"` directly  (as if no `dist` subfolder)

While Cyclic docs may not be explicit about it, if you define an [output path](https://docs.cyclic.sh/overview/build#output-path), the latter becomes the current working directory of your final app bundle. That is why that output path must also contain your `package.json` file.

And another consequence is that all runtime file paths (in particular for the `start` script) are relative to that new cwd.

Therefore in your case, after build you have:

```
/lol-pickem-api
└── dist
    ├── src
    │   └── server.js
    └── package.json
```

With Output Path: `lol-pickem-api/dist`, Cyclic bundles only that subdirectory, which becomes the cwd.

When launching your app, Cyclic then finds the `package.json` file inside, with a `start` script and executes it.

The path is now relative to the cwd, hence `server.js` is in `src` subfolder. And you can just execute `node src/server.js`.

---

Additionally, make sure your `node_modules` dependencies are also available within your `dist` output path: as mentioned above, only that folder is bundled, so you need to have:

```
/lol-pickem-api
└── dist
    ├── node_modules
    ├── src
    │   └── server.js
    └── package.json
```

Comment: IIRC correctly, I tried that and I actually had the package.json as a sibling to the dist folder, not inside of it. I will try again and circle back though. Thank you!

Comment: Update: I can see that, upon building, the deployment in Cyclic has the `package.json` as a sibling to a `src` folder with all the code in it. I changed the start script to `node src/server.js`, but I still get the following error `Error: Cannot find module 'express'` but express is clearly in my `package.json` : `"express": "^4.17.1",`

Comment: Indeed I did not pay attention that your `server.ts` file is within a `src` subfolder, I fixed above code. About `express` (and any other dependency), you have to move your `node_modules` folder within `dist` as well (e.g. as last build step), see modified answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks for modifying! Is there a standard way for TypeScript to move `node_modules` into `dist`?

Comment: "_Is there a standard way for TypeScript to move_ [folders]?": no, it is not a core TS job. You could e.g. use a `mv` command in a `postbuild` script. Or a symlink, if Cyclic resolves it.

Comment: `"postbuild": "mv node_modules ./dist",` worked for me. Thanks again I am all good here!